# Can we use both coredata and SQlite in a iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am currently using CoreData as data base in my app. Now I have a requirement to fetch data from a SQLite DB file and use that in my app. Now the questions are

1 - Can we use both SQLite and CoreData together in a single app.

2 - If yes, will it cause any memory issues?

3 - Can we fetch data from multiple DB(SQLite DB) files in a single app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Probably not.
3. Yes.

SQLite is just a library that lets you read and write files in its own format using SQL statements. There are no special restrictions on accessing multiple files. You can even write queries that span multiple databases — see the [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) statement.

Comment: haha... +1 Marcelo... Nice one word answers..... This reminded me of Steve jobs... Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: @AforAlpha: No probs. I can do worse than being compared to Steve. However, I couldn't resist embellishing my answer just a little bit. :-)

Comment: i wish i could add another +1, but fortunately or unfortunately i was allowed to up vote just once :)

Comment: A for Alpha, May I suggest that you accept Marcelo's answer by checking the green check mark next to it? Andrew

Comment: Just to confirm.  I am working on an app that has multiple CoreData stores and a separate sqlite3 database accessed through sqlite.  (This is due to the use of a few libraries we have that each have their own CoreData store as well as needing to use the clients sqlite database).  No issues have cropped up.